# ajax call handling on asp.net serverside

Tags: asp.net

I'm working on an asp.net project based on asp.net AJAX but we get more and more client side calls using jquery ($.ajax) and get json or html return. I'm wondering what is the best way to handle these calls on the server side, in the same webform, or use a specific http handler, or even web service? can somebody share the experience or best practice?
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you an http handler. Normally it's the best and simplest option.

There is no problem on managing the ajax call using a page method (marked as WebMethod and static), the only drawback is that can be only be called from that page. The http handler is independent and can be called from any page.

The web service is normally suitable for calling third party API, I don't see that you need to create one for ajax calls on your own web site.